# What is the plural form of "breve"?

Tags: plural-forms

The word "breve" here means [musical note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_whole_note), its duration is equal to two whole notes (like how the duration of a whole is equal to two half notes and so on).
It has another singular form — "brevis".

What is the plural form of "breve" or "brevis"? How do I correctly say "two 'breve's"?

Variants "*two breves*" and "*two brevises*" seem incorrect for me.

P.S.: I can't use "double", since in my case this word already stands for another thing.

Comment: Cambridge gives this definition. It also lists it as Countable. The definition shows a plural form
› a ​musical ​note with a ​time ​value ​equal to two ​semibreves     http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/breve

Comment: I have never heard the plural of breve used, but i have heard the plural of senibreve used, an i imagine that breve would follow the same pattern, so I'd go for **two breves**.

Comment: It's just "breves" /briːvz/.

Comment: On that note, **breves** are not much used nowadays for dynamism in music, and now we have many more devices as to denote a long note.

Comment: The other part of the question was about the alternative form 'brevis'. This is an even more technical musical and poetic term, and it, strictly speaking, has a Latin plural 'brevēs' (approximately 'bre-vays'). Probably no-one actually uses that in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably just "breves". This sounds okay to my native ear.

- `One breve`
- `Two breves`
- `Hundreds of breves`

The word is foreign in origin, and not really used outside of music, so I see why it might cause confusion.